# PHP - Bank like monthly transactions

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, cron, banking

Im not sure what search terms to type in.

I'm building a basic system for a letting agents to record rents paid in, I have done this no problem.

The next step is to do repeatable transactions of when the rent is due, is their any tutorials or advise on how I should complete this feat?

For example:

Tenant 1 needs to pay £2 rent on the first of every month.

Tenant 2 needs to pay £1 rent every four weeks.

Comment: have a look at [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 1):

In a table you will have

```
T1:
Tenant_id | repeatable | next_due
```

And in another table you will have

```
T2:
Tenant_id | Rent_date
```

Using a query like:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
T1 JOIN
  (SELECT
    tenant_id, MAX(Rent_date) LastRent
  FROM
    T2
  GROUP BY 
    tenant_id
  ) MaxT2 on T1.tenant_id = MaxT2.tenant_id
WHERE
  MaxT2.LastRent + repeatable > T1.next_due
```

When you find something in this SELECT, insert into T2 the transaction for current rate and in T1 update next_due with Rent_date + repeatable

Put this script in a file and using a cron - make it run daily (preferable in the morning).

This is just a quick answer. You will have to take care of repeatable field (to represent for example number of days, or weeks, or every 10th day of the month).

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is what I was looking for. The repeatable could be an issue, some pay every four weeks and some the X of every month. I think I can find a solution, now you have provided the insight into the query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use crontabs to this very task,

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    php /path/to/hourly.php
25 6    * * *   root    php daily.php
47 6    * * 7   root    php weekly.php
52 6    1 * *   root    php monthly.php
```

smth like this...

Answer (score 0):

You could keep four fields - `payment_date`,`recurring_days_interval`,`owe`,`price` for every payment record.
Then, on a cronjob that runs every day, you check if we hit the days interval, and if so add the `price` to the current `owe`. Once the person pays some or all of the bill, you reduce it from `owe`.

The query you should run daily should be something like:

`UPDATE payments SET owe=COALESCE(owe, 0)+COALESCE(price, 0) WHERE recurring_days_interval IS NOT NULL AND DATE_ADD(payment_date, INTERVAL recurring_days_interval DAY) > NOW()`

If you want to stop the recurring, just set `recurring_days_interval` to `NULL`.

Comment: I need more of a bank transaction system other than a balance system. Thank you, your respond helped my understanding of the issue.